# rac_signalForSelector: needs empty implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a class that implements the UICollectionViewDelegate protocol.

I'm using rac_signalForSelector: to register selection like this:

```
[self rac_signalForSelector:@selector(collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:)]
```

but it only fires if I leave in an empty implementation of collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath: like this:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Empty
}
```

I tried with rac_signalForSelector:fromProtocol: as well without luck.

I'm using Reactive Cocoa 2.2.4

Thanks, 
Mikkel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you call `-rac_signalForSelector:` **before** you set your object as a delegate. Some Apple frameworks will check to see if your class responds to a certain delegate method selector when you set the delegate object, and cache that information, so if you haven't called `-rac_signalForSelector:` by that time and you don't explicitly implement the method, those delegate methods won't ever get called.

Comment: There's a an inelegant but usable workaround: assign `nil` as the delegate and then reassign the real delegate object, which busts the selector caching. Do this if you use `-rac_signalForSelector:` after previously assigning a delegate.