# How might I use ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal to "RACify" a UIApplicationDelegate lifecycle event like didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Tags: objective-c, functional-programming, reactive-cocoa, racsignal, reactive-cocoa-3

I am wondering how I might go about using the `ReactiveCocoa` library to `RAC`-ify `UIApplicationDelegate` lifecycle events.

Since the most important one is `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`, that seems like a logical place to start to me.

The basic idea, if I understand correctly, would be to create a `RACSignal` that would encapsulate the event (application finished launching with these options), send it either serially through a pipeline or in parallel to multiple "application start handlers" and then merge all of their outputs - if serially, then only continue when each returns `YES`, if parallel, `if (handler1 == YES && handler2 == YES ...)` - and then `return` the combined response in the actual `UIApplicationDelegate`.

However, I am fuzzy on the precise details of how this would be accomplished - which is probably evident from my line of questioning.

Any examples, either in real code or just pseudo-code, would be greatly appreciated. It would for me (and probably others) serve a dual purpose: 1) the stated one, and 2) provide an example of how to `RAC`-ify a non-UI-driven event (well, that's not even exactly true, but I think you see what I mean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I could wrap the delegate methods using `signalForSelector` carefully.

I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22000433/rac-signalforselector-needs-empty-implementation) to use `rac_signalForSelector` *before* setting the delegate.

For `UIApplicationDelegate` it is potentially a bit more complicated because we don't usually set `UIApplication` `delegate` directly but instead specify a class in the `main.m` file in the case of Objective-C or in `main.swift` [in the case of Swift](http://letvargo.mooo.com/creating-your-own-main-swift-file/).

However, I believe that if the setup is done in the `AppDelegate` class itself, and it is assigned in the `main` file, this will satisfy the requirement stated above.

Another choice is to add the methods to the interface of a new Objective-C category or Swift extension to a `UIResponder` subclass.

[An example can be found here.](https://gist.github.com/dewind/8795714)